# How to substitute string.split() used in Python 2 to Python 3 code?

Tags: python

When I run the following code (from chapter 19 of [*Introduction to Computation 
and Programming Using Python*](https://www.amazon.co.uk/Introduction-Computation-Programming-Using-Python/dp/0262525003) by John Guttag):

```
dataFile = open(fName, 'r')
    for line in dataFile:
        dataLine = string.split(line[:-1], ',')
```

I receive the following error:

```
error message:module 'string' has no attribute 'split'
```

Comment: That must be a really old book. In Python 2, the `string.split` function has been deprecated in favour of the `str` type's `.split` method for ages.

Answer (score 1):

Change this

```
dataLine = string.split(line[:-1], ',')
```

to this

```
dataLine = line[:-1].split(',')
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't define the `string` anywhere. It shouldn't work on python 2 or 3. You might want two `::`, but that's for you to find out.

```
dataFile = open(fName, 'r')
    for line in dataFile:
        dataLine = line[:-1].split(',')
```